# Website setting to default compatibility mode

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

The asp.net website on server when opened in IE browser, the site opens in compatibility view with Document mode set to IE7.

I have not set any meta tag for this kind of rendering.

Can anyone suggest me why it is happening so? I need the site to get rendered in normal mode and not in compatibility view in IE10

Answer (score 1):

add this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

**Note:** `IE=100` will work for `IE 9.0++.`

Set it to `content="IE=edge"` to ensure it always uses the latest version of IE!

use it just after the title

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Web</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```